# multiple type signatures of Numba cuda.jit

Tags: arrays, cuda, numba

I meet a problem if I have multiple choices of type signatures in cuda.jit. In my function, I will reset `data` back to `ref` if `done` flag is on. The `data` type could be int32 or float32 array. It is just for experiment, do not bother with the dummy function itself. This function is running well if I just use `cuda.jit`, so I am pretty sure there is some issue with my type declare, but it looks like a correct way from the documentation. BTW, I am using Numba 0.54.

```
from numba import cuda 
from numba import float32, int32


@cuda.jit([(int32[:], int32[:], int32[:], int32),
           (float32[:], float32[:], int32[:], int32)])
def reset_when_done(data, ref, done, force_reset):
    env_id = cuda.blockIdx.x
    tid = cuda.threadIdx.x
    if tid == 0:
        if force_reset > 0.5 or done[env_id] > 0.5:
            data[env_id] = ref[env_id]
```

And I got the error

```
TypeError: [(array(int32, 1d, A), array(int32, 1d, A), array(int32, 1d, A), int32), (array(float32, 1d, A), array(float32, 1d, A), array(int32, 1d, A), int32)] is not a callable object
```

Comment: It isn’t obvious what you are trying to do here. The first argument to `numba.cuda.jit` is always either a function or a signature of a function. What you have passed is a list…

Comment: @talonmies, I am trying to provide two different possible types of signatures, according to numba.jit, "https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/jit-compilation.html#jit-functions", the signature is either a single signature or a list of signatures representing the expected Types and signatures of function arguments and return values. 
Not sure if cuda.jit shares the same format, but if this is not the syntax, is there any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter of `cuda.jit` needs to be either a signature or a function regarding the documentation. The same is true for the CPU JIT. The thing is the signature can be a list of basic signatures with the CPU JIT and not with CUDA JIT so far. **This is a bug**. It has been [**reported**](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/3226), still opened and plan to be fixed in **Numba 0.57**.

Comment: ah, sounds like exactly the problem. Thank you